# How to edit a particular section in a web application?

Tags: jquery, spring, web, refresh, edit

I've created a web application using Spring. In one of the page I've three sections personal info, family info and professional info. I've a separate table in DB for each section. I am querying data from 3 tables and showing in UI.

Now I've to introduce edit link on top of each section and user should be able edit each section. I've 3 approach but not sure which one to use.

1. When user clicks the edit link. Query the DB with the user id(it will be available in link as a parameter)and fetch data from DB(repetitive job)for the particular section and show the value in text box in a new screen. User can edit the values and click submit.
2. Have 6 sections. 3 sections with label and data and 3 sections with text box with data. Using JQuery hide all the 3 sections with text box with data on load. When user clicks edit link just hide section with label and data and show only text box with submit button.
3. Have 3 sections with text boxes but change the style and make it look like label. when the user clicks edit link then change the look to text box.

Could you please suggest a better way.

Question: 2

I've both submit and cancel button on edit screen for all the 3 sections. If a user edits a particular field and clicks the cancel button how to restore the default values without querying the DB once again?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is depended on the data you have and frequency that user edit your data.
   If size of the data is high and edit frequency is relatively law then the first approach is the best one. Since you don't want to load all the data when page load, only when user request to edit query the data base and get data.

If you have small size of data and performance is a key parameter then use second approach since user don't want to wait to edit data (Initial loading may take considerable amount of time)

2. After you load the data store it in a variable in case of user cancel edit just restore the content from this variable.